# In tensorflow what is the difference between trainable and stop gradient

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to know the difference between the option `trainable=False` and the `tf.stop_gradient()`. If I make the `trainable` option `False` will my optimizer not consider the variable for training? 
Does this option make the it a constant value throughout the training?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> trainable=False

Here the variable value will be constant throughout the training. Optimizer won't consider this variable for training, no gradient update op.

> stop_gradient

In certain situations, you want to calculate the gradient of a op with respect to some variable keeping a few other variables constant; but for other ops you may use those variables also to calculate gradient. So here you can't use `trinable=False`, as you need those variable for training with other ops.

`stop_gradient` is very useful for ops; you can selectively optimize a op with respect to select few variables while keeping other constant.

```
y1 = tf.stop_gradient(W1x+b1)
y2 = W2y1+b2
cost = cost_function(y2, y)
# this following op wont optimize the cost with respect to W1 and b1
train_op_w2_b2 = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.001, 0.9).minimize(cost)

W1 = tf.get_variable('w1', trainable=False)
y1 = W1x+b1
y2 = W2y1+b2
cost = cost_function(y2, y)
# this following op wont optimize the cost with respect to W1
train_op = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.001, 0.9).minimize(cost)
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. If I want a variable to be constant throughout the training I would use `trainable=False`. But if I want conditionally a variable to be trained and sometimes I do not want it to be trained I would use `stop_gradient`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: that's what i meant.

Comment: In your first example, the same effect can be achieved if you remove `stop_gradient` and use `trainable=False` for W1 and b1, right? Can you give an example where setting `trainable=False` won't work but `stop_gradient` will?